# What Kind of Space Problems Do You Solve with Python and other prosaic software tools?

Tags: spacex, software, business

In looking at different job listings for space companies, I see some tools which are obviously specific to aerospace and high-end engineering, but also a lot of very run of the mill software skills like Python, C#, or Rust.

Obviously, there are some mundane problems you need to solve even at a cool space company, but I wonder what kind of space-oriented problems these companies are using them to solve. I would love it if someone with some background in this area could shed some light.

Comment: voting to close as opinion-based because there will be a billion different answers. Space companies write software to solve all the problems software can solve. Like with other software there will also be toolchain development around it.

Comment: have a skim through these https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python I wouldn't be surprised if most will be on orbit and propagation subjects and will require a grasp of the relevant physics and numerical methods. This will just be a very narrow sample of the length and breadth of physics and engineering problems that could be supported

Comment: This is probably too open-ended. I personally wrote a ton of little things using generic software tools (little simulations, procedure checking tools, ad nauseum).

Comment: @Puffin - that is very helpful

Comment: JPL’s Solar System Dynamics (SSD) group provides several [APIs](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/api.html). It's relatively easy to access those APIs using any language, but I prefer Python.

Comment: I've got what I need, so y'all can close it of you want. Kind of feel like I got a great answer to the question I was asking, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of them.

You want to collect data from a sensor, package it into a telemetry packet? C is probably your tool (although I know people who've done this in Logo).

You want to process it for ops on the ground? Maybe Python.

Over the last couple of decades, I've written space-related software  in C, assembly, CUDA, Forth, Mathematica, Python, and even AWK. FORTRAN and PL/I farther in the past. Whatever gets the job done.

The only specialized language was a DSL of my own devising that I used for CCD clock sequencer programming on TESS.

Comment: I know most of these but what is DSL?

Comment: @OrganicMarble Domain Specific Language.

Comment: Thanks for the info!

Comment: @OrganicMarble Found the doc for it. https://github.com/TESScience/tessfpe/wiki/Sequencer-Domain-Specific-Language-Tutorial